# Spark DataFrame - Struct type for Array of Key and value columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Sample DataSet

```
B7J;B7J Realty Corp;[street#939 W El Camino,city#Chicago,state#IL]
AGC;AGC Companies Incorporated;[street#415 N Mary Ave,city#Long Island,state#NY]
KBB;KBB Minerals International Inc;[street#2373 S Archer Ave,city#Jersey City,state#NJ]
```

First row -- Company short name , company full name and company address. 
here first column and second columns are very straight forward and implemented. but how can i implement Address column . written like this

```
val companySchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("Company_key", StringType),
    StructField("Company_Name", StringType),
    StructField("Company_Address", StringType)));
```

But will not help to find city? how can re format the schema.